# Linear program to minimize distance between towers and citizen

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to obtain the best coverage of towers around citizens, so they can walk as little as possible to reach a tower.

Let the position of all citizens as $ \{ (a_k, b_k) \mid k \in [1, c] \} $ and the position of all towers as $ \{ (x_n, y_n) \mid n \in [1, t] \} $. Where $ c, t \in \mathbb{N} $ resp. the number of citizens and the number of towers.

I want to find a linear program that computes $ (x_n, y_n) $ such as the sum of each distance between $ (x_n, y_n) $ (towers) and all $ (a_k, b_k) $ (citizens) is minimal.

Comment: How many towers are there?

Comment: @healynr there is 1 to t towers

Comment: Search term: *multisource Weber problem*.  This problem is nonconvex nonlinear.